# Evil thoughts during salah

Tags: tawba, forgiveness

Asalamualaikum I wanted to know some remedy for evil thoughts ....... actually worse than evil .....I get these thoughts especially during salah I don't understand why ....This thing is driving me crazy .....I don't mean any of those thoughts but they jus pop out of nowhere ...and wallah such bad thoughts that I can stand in the prayer ...plzz help me ...I love Allah and Nabi saw but these thoughts are driving me away from Allah and salah ........why do the thoughts come during salah .......

Comment: Possibly relevant https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/8209/what-to-do-if-i-forget-surah-during-salat/8213#8213

Answer (score 0):

It is the waswas, infact don’t pay attention to it and keep on ignoring it and these thoughts will go away brother. I used to have the same thoughts when doing a worship act or when reading about the religions, and just to assure you, the reason you get these thoughts is because you have iman which the shiatsu wants to drive you away from.

Answer (score 0):

hey hmm maybe do u suffer from ocd? theres ocd thing called 'intrusive thoughts' but don't want to scare you, it could be just that you care and love Allah so much you are thinking too hard of not doing thinking wrong so then u have bad thoughts as u think oh i dont want bad thoughts..... it happens to people you are not alone it happen to me also... but u just need to not stress and pause about these thoughts as it makes it worse. you should just carry on when u get a thought and know its not really you thinking these things its just u not wanting to think bad thoughts so they pop in... just dont even acknowledge them and carry on... pray for help, I pray for you, praise Allah